# How does Pet Battle experience work?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

World of Warcraft now has a feature called Pet Battles, which allows you to fight both NPCs and players with your companion pets. I have noticed while doing pet battles that there are various situations where you get more XP (like attacking higher level enemies with a lower level pet) or don't seem to get experience at all (like if your pet dies during the battle, but one of your other pets still wins the battle for you).

How does Pet Battle experience work? What conditions provide an experience bonus and under what conditions do you get less experience?

Are there any other actions than winning that provide experience for your pets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This article over at WoW wiki details battle pet experience gains](http://www.wowwiki.com/Pet_Battle_System#Leveling)! I think you'll find what you'll need.

> How catching affects level:
>
> - Catching any pet level 15 or under retains its current level.
> - Catching a level 16-20 pet will lose 1 level.
> - Catching a level 21-25 pet will lose 2 levels.
> - The XP required to level for pets after level 10 has been dramatically reduced.
>
> **Calculating experience**
>
> If your pet team prevails in combat, experience is awarded to all
>   surviving pets that participated in combat. Pets that do not enter
>   combat have no effect on the experience awarded. Similarly, pets that
>   die in combat also have no affect on the experience awarded. The
>   experience that dead pets would have received is not "lost". Instead,
>   the system considers dead pets the same way as non-participating pets.
>
> When you defeat an opposing pet, the experience awarded is calculated
>   using this formula:
>
> ```
> [opponent level + 9] X [level difference + 5]
> ```
>
> The level difference is capped at +2, so there is no benefit to
>   defeating an opponent more than 2 levels higher than your pet. If your
>   pet is 5 or more levels higher than the opponent, it will receive zero
>   experience.
>
> When your opponent is level 5 or higher, there will be two of them,
>   and you receive experience for each of them (200% normal experience).
>   When your opponent is level 15 or higher, there will be three of them,
>   and you receive full experience for the first two, and half experience
>   for the third (250% normal experience).
>
> The quality of the defeated pet does not affect experience gain, and
>   you get full experience if you capture or defeat your opponent.
>
> The experience awarded to each surviving pet is calculated by dividing
>   the experience in the table below by the number of surviving pets:

*For more information on battle pet experience, [see the WoW wiki article](http://www.wowwiki.com/Pet_Battle_System#Leveling)*.

Comment: Alright, so if I start a pet as my first pet in a battle, but as it's first action, swap it out for another pet, does that still count as showing up enough to get XP?